# Chat app synchronization on background in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, notifications, chat

I have a chat application developed by JS. I want to send PING to server once in a while. Its not a problem if app runs on fore ground. The problem is when user minimizes it or open another app. My app looses its focus and gets into suspended state.

I have following two use-cases.

1. To keep the chat session open I need to send `PING` to server (Its an IRC server) every `X` minutes even the app runs in background.
2. We also need to check for new messages (by ajax on a local http server) and add a local notification to the notification queue so when user clicks on it app can resume

I have found apple does not allow running apps in the background. if they allow they require special permission. I found some apps does it by requesting finite length execution time. 
What is the best way to get highest possible background execution time?  As a chat app can I request permission for `voip`, `location` or any other way ?

Note: the app will be running in an environment where **there is no Internet**. Hence **push notification will not work** here.

**Update**: After doing a lot searching I found [*background fetch*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56). It seem *background fetch* will suite it. But still the problem remains, its not called in a timely manner.

Comment: There is no solution. You can't use location or similar just in an attempt to keep running in the background if your app is not location based. The best bet would be voip IF your app is eligible, you don't provide sufficient info to assess if it would be or not. If not then the only alternative is background fetch. Such is iOS, you have to live with its limitations, there is no magic solution for trying to get background execution is your app if not entitled to it according to Apple restrictions.

Comment: If you really achieve this, you are going to get a Nobel prize for sure. How come will you provide chat service without any network activity and having an HTTP server running at the same time?

Comment: @Mert is it possible to avoid apples approval if enterprise distribution is used? In that case should voip solve it?

Comment: AFAIK you can't deceive Apple on fake VOIP usage. Beyond that, you can't make use of VOIP without IP, you need network anyway.

Comment: There is *no* Internet, But IP is available. There *is* network.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like an interesting problem. From reading the various comments, it sounds like you want this to work when you're on a local network - so you have wifi, but the wifi router/base station isn't connected to the actual internet?

Because background refresh isn't going to be predictable - you'll never know when it is going to update - you might want to get creative.

You could look into exploiting iOS VOIP support, only without the Voice! [Apple has some tips on VOIP here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12). VOIP basically uses something called SIP (Session Initiation Protocol), which is signalling layer of the call, and a lot like HTTP. It's this SIP layer that you want to take advantage of.

This isn't going to be terribly easy, but it should be achievable. Setup your app to use VOIP, and then look into something like [PJSip](http://www.pjsip.org/) as your SIP library. Then, on your local network have a SIP Server (I'm sure there are plenty open source implementations) that you can register your iPhone against (so your server knows where your phone is, pretending to be a VOIP phone). This should work, because it doesn't need to go through Apple *as far as I am aware...* And will run happily on your local network.

Then, the server can send a message via SIP to the handset, as if it were instigating a VOIP session. You app is awoken, gets the messages - ideally from the SIP message if possible - and then just doesn't start the session. SIP was designed just for creating sessions, not just VOIP. When I worked in Telecoms R&D (a long time ago) we were using it to swap between Text/Voice/Video, all using local servers.

You'll have to jump a lot of hoops to make this work, but it would be pretty awesome. I have never tried this actual use case - especially with iOS, but I'm fairly sure it will work. It is a bit of a fudge, but should get you where you need to go.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, the router isn't connected to internet

Comment: One more thing, It seems the app wont be public and it'll be inside an enterprise. So I believe apples approval is not necessary in this case. Though we want to distribute it to several enterprises

Comment: In that case, you should be fine. SIP should do the job. The iPhone will keep the socket open and you can push messages to the device like they were phone calls! Sounds like awesome fun. I'm a little bit jealous you get to build it!

Comment: If apple does not need to verify enterprise app, cant I just enable the voip mode on xcode and able to send http request without SIP?

Comment: I was thinking about that today. I'm not 100% sure, but quite probably. This would mean you can just user your proprietary protocol to do the whole thing!

Comment: Could you elaborate "proprietary protocol to do the whole thing"

Comment: Yes - you mention in an answer to another comment that your chat app is based on proprietary technology, so depending on how that works you may be able to use it in place of SIP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like PubNub to build this chat app with iOS using native Objective-C code, or with the Phonegap (Cordova) libs.

The beauty with using a real-time messaging network like PubNub is that when the app goes to the background, you can easily have the chat messages come in on APNS.

When the app is in the foreground, it can just receive them as the native (PubNub) message. And if it needs to "catch-up" with the messages it missed while in the background (but received via APNS), its trivial to implement.

Also, PubNub is platform agnostic -- so you can easily also use it on Web, Android, BB, Windows Phone, etc.

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-real-time-chat-10-lines-code/

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/html5-websockets-beautiful-real-time-chat-on-mobile-using-pubnubs-channel-presence/

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS

https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/master/phonegap

geremy

Comment: But, if you mean that you will NEVER have Internet (not only in certain instances), this may not work for you :)

Comment: There is no Internet. we are providing chat and other services to people who dont have Internet.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im how do you suppose connect people w/o connection to the internet? Or do you mean bonjour on local WiFi network?

Comment: @moonlight No, we are not using bonjour. Its a proprietary technology. We just provide chat service.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im For PubNub clients to be able to work, they should be able to reach PubNub remote services (on HTTP, HTTPS ports). Does PubNub client work now properly using your `proprietary` technology? As for working in background - you can't just select required background mode without actual usage of selected mode. If you will select `voip` and will stop communication with server, application will be suspended + Apple may decide to reject it. Same with other modes.

Comment: There is a http server where we are providing services. but no Internet is available. BTW. I dont want to use PubNub. It'll not solve the problem

Comment: This answer does not adhere to the very basic requirement on the question.